# Firebase cloud functions visibility and editing

Tags: google-cloud-functions

My question is very simple I am new to Firebase cloud functions. Can some user can they see whats written in my function and can they find http url and call them outside my app. Because I will include admin SDK in function so I need credentials to be private. I want to decode uid from token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for your Cloud Functions is only visible to you and collaborators on the project. It is not visible to other users of your app.